# Django choice field default value and readonly

Tags: django

I try to set my field in form readonly and put any default value. 
This is a part of my form:

```
category = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly':
                                                             'readonly'}),
                               initial=Category.objects.get(name='Zdrowie i uroda'))

class Meta:
    model = Site
    fields = ('url', 'name', 'description', 'keywords', 'group', 'category',
              'subcategory', 'category1', 'subcategory1')
```

I get an error: Cannot assign "'Zdrowie i uroda'": "Site.category" must be a "Category" instance.

This is my site model:

```
class Site(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category')
    subcategory = ChainedForeignKey(
        'SubCategory',
        chained_field='category',
        chained_model_field='category',
        show_all=False,
        auto_choose=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    description = models.TextField()
    # importuje zmienione TextFields widgets.py
    keywords = MyTextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, editable=False)
    url = models.URLField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    category1 = models.ForeignKey('Category', related_name='category', blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    subcategory1 = ChainedForeignKey(
        'SubCategory',
        chained_field='category1',
        chained_model_field='category',
        related_name='subcategory',
        show_all=False,
        auto_choose=True, blank=True, null=True, default=None)

    group = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=(('podstawowy', 'podstawowy'),
                                                     ('premium', 'premium')), default='podstawowy')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('site', args=[str(self.category.slug),
                                     str(self.subcategory.slug), str(self.id)])

    def get_thumb(self):
        host = urlparse(self.url).hostname
        if host.startswith('www.'):
            host = host[4:]
        thumb = 'http://free4.pagepeeker.com/v2/thumbs.php?size=s&url=' + host
        return thumb

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Strony"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I can't deal with it. Any clues?

Finally I excluded category, subcategory fields from my model.form and added it to html source manually:

```
{{ form_extended|bootstrap }}
                    <label for="example-text-input" class="col-2 col-form-label">Category</label>
                    <input class="form-control form-control-lg" type="text" name="category" disabled required value="{{ form_extended.initial.category.name }} " />
                    <label for="example-text-input" class="col-2 col-form-label">Subcategory</label>
                    <input class="form-control form-control-lg" type="text" name="subcategory" disabled required value="{{ form_extended.initial.subcategory.name }} " />
```

I don't think it is a right way but I can't put some data to form initial values. Should I create my form manually from scratch? My way isn't good because I use jQuery to extend form. Now category, subcategory fields are las but they shouldn't (when user choose "premium" group from choice fields, after subcategory field there should appear "category1", "subcategory1" fields...

As always - I am sorry for my terrible English. Every post is like exam to me.

Comment: post your full traceback

Comment: full traceback - http://dpaste.com/142GV5V

Comment: why dont you try `initial='Fitness'` only ?

Comment: Fitness is subcategory. I try to set category first ('Zdrowie i uroda'). Full url is http://127.0.0.1:8000/zdrowie-i-uroda/fitness/

Answer (score 1):

Options without further delving into Django forms:

#### Change Model Field

This might not be an option, but you could try setting:

```
class Site(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', editable=False)
```

Remove the explicit declaration of the category form field from your form and simply set the initial category when initializing the form or override `__init__` to set it.

#### Change Form Field

Django would normally render a ForeignKeyField as drop down. Do you explicitly want a text input instead? In that case you have to handle data validation and the data mapping yourself.

A way of working around that would be to remove the explicit declaration of the form field and simply handle this field separatly in your HTML template:

```
<input type="text" name="category" value="{{ form.initial.category.name }}" />
```

---

> "Do you explicitly want a text input instead?" - No.

In that case, you want a [ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) instead of a `CharField`.

```
category = forms.ModelChoiceField(
    queryset=Category.objects,
    empty_label=None,
    disabled=True,  # Django 1.9+
    initial=Category.objects.get(name='Zdrowie i uroda'))
```

Comment: "Do you explicitly want a text input instead?" - No. Site looks like: category,->subcategory. In subcategory.view there is a form to fill. I would like to fill category, subcategory fields with values from url (http://127.0.0.1:8000/zdrowie-i-uroda/fitness/). In admin panel there should be possibility to change those categories/subcategories.

Comment: I can't deal with it. Finally I excluded category, subcategory fields from my form and put it directly to my html source: